# Rails and RVM: Where to find .rvm folder to access update_system.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM on Mavericks OS X 9. It didn't work, and sent me off chasing username/.rmv file for a log. Where do I find that file? I go to Finder but there's no .rmv in my username (Christopherd) file.

In detail,
I ran:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

and later got this:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing macports..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................christopherd password required for 'make install': .......
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
/Users/christopherd/.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_port: line 34: port: command not found
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',
please read /Users/christopherd/.rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Then I did this, but I still couldn't find any help :/

```
Christophers-Mac:~ christopherd$ chflags nohidden ~/Library
Christophers-Mac:~ christopherd$ .rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
-bash: .rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log: Permission denied
Christophers-Mac:~ christopherd$ cd .rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
-bash: cd: .rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log: Not a directory
Christophers-Mac:~ christopherd$
```

### #

Update:

Here's what I found when I went to the log:

```
[2013-11-21 08:57:40] requirements_osx_port_update_system
requirements_osx_port_update_system () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo port -dv selfupdate || return $?
}
current path: /Users/christopherd/.rvm/src/rvm
command(2): requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247
sudo: port: command not found
```

Thanks for the help in getting me to this point! One down, more to go. I'm trying some workarounds, just getting back into the solution.

Comment: 1) add this file `/Users/christopherd/.rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log` 2) open a bug report here => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself. It's trying to find the Macports binary that it just installed, but it's not in your shell's path. If you look at the log output, it actually successfully installed the binary but I think it did not properly re-load the shell with the new path definition.

The easiest thing to do is close your shell window and open a new one. Then run this to try again:

```
rvm install 2.0.0-p247
```

If that still doesn't work, [go here and manually install Macports again](http://www.macports.org/install.php). Close and reopen your shell after installing, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to do something along the lines of:

   `less /Users/christopherd/.rvm/log/1385052252_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log` to see the log from your Terminal
2. RVM has nothing to do with your `~/Library` folder, the `chflags nohidden ~/Library` is not needed.
3. Directories starting with a dot (`.`) are hidden in Finder by default.

   You can see all dotfiles via: `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES && killall Finder`